# Generate random rows and keep an order between observations to create a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'd would to generate more than 100 rows randomly and keep the link within the observations.
Below my example :
There are 4 variables which are `Country`, `Category`, `Product` and `Price`.
And `Category`, `Product` need to have a link together.

```
import random as rd
import pandas as pd

Country = []
Category = []
Product = []
Price = []

for i in range(1000):
    Country.append(rd.choice(['England','Germany','France','USA','China','Japan']))
    Category.append(rd.choice(['Electronics','home appliances','Computer','Food','Bedding']))
    Product.append(rd.choice(['Iphone 6S','Samsung Fridge','PC ASUS','Cheese','Bed']))
    Price.append(rd.randint(10,10000))

data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Country':Country,'Category':Category,'Product':Product,'Price':Price})
```

When I executed the code above, Category observations aren't with their corresponding Product observations. For example you could have a row with Electronics (Category) and Cheese (Product) and it makes no sens obviously.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column by dictionary with `zip` of `lists` after generating `DataFrame` without column `Product`:

Also append to lists is not necessary, faster is use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

```
import numpy as np

N = 10000
L0 = ['England','Germany','France','USA','China','Japan']
L1 = ['Electronics','home appliances','Computer','Food','Bedding']
L2 = ['Iphone 6S','Samsung Fridge','PC ASUS','Cheese','Bed']
d = dict(zip(L1, L2))
print (d)
{'Electronics': 'Iphone 6S', 'home appliances': 'Samsung Fridge', 
 'Computer': 'PC ASUS', 'Food': 'Cheese', 'Bedding': 'Bed'}
```

---

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Country':np.random.choice(L0, size=N),
                            'Category':np.random.choice(L1, size=N),
                            'Price':np.random.randint(10,size=N)})
data['Product'] = data['Category'].map(d)
print (data)
      Country         Category  Price         Product
0     Germany             Food      1          Cheese
1     England             Food      6          Cheese
2       Japan          Bedding      3             Bed
3      France      Electronics      1       Iphone 6S
4       Japan  home appliances      8  Samsung Fridge
      ...              ...    ...             ...
9995  England      Electronics      3       Iphone 6S
9996    China      Electronics      1       Iphone 6S
9997  Germany          Bedding      0             Bed
9998      USA      Electronics      3       Iphone 6S
9999  Germany  home appliances      6  Samsung Fridge

[10000 rows x 4 columns]
```